# TableOfContent sticking to top right corner while scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have created a `table-of-contents` component in my Angular app with just two items to display.

I have written the following code for each script:

**ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { pdfDefaultOptions } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-of-contents',
  templateUrl: './table-of-contents.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-of-contents.component.css']
})
export class TableOfContentsComponent implements OnInit {

  AOK_pdf_viewer_source: string = "/assets/AOK_T2DM.pdf";

  constructor() { pdfDefaultOptions.assetsFolder = 'assets'; }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="tableOfContentContainer">
  <div class="tableOfContent docs-toc-container">
    <div class="docs-toc-heading">Table of Contents</div>
    <nav>
      <a
        href="../assets/AOK_T2DM.pdf"
        class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"
        >Download AOK Brochure</a
      >
      <br />
      <a
        href="https://scholar.google.at/scholar?as_ylo=2021&q=diabetes&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1"
        class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"
        >2021 Articles on Diabetes</a
      >
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
    [src]="AOK_pdf_viewer_source"
    [height]="'100%'"
    width="100%"
    [useBrowserLocale]="true"
    backgroundColor="#000000"
    [textLayer]="true"
    [showHandToolButton]="true"
    zoom="page-width"
  >
  </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.tableOfContentContainer {
    right: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.docs-toc-container {
    border-left: 4px solid #3f51b5;
    font-weight: 700;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

a:hover {
    color: #3f51b5;
}

.tableOfContent {
    padding: 5px 0 10px 10px;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

My table-of-contents sticks to the page fixed while scrolling down, which is what I initially wanted.

What do I change in my code to change the behavior to sticking to the top right corner of the page and remaining in view all the time as the user scrolls up and down the page?

p.s. I am looking at the code on [this](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) page, but cannot figure out how to modify my code. Can someone please help me understand how I can achieve a similar TableOfCntent as this tutorial page but very simply?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed`:

```
.tableOfContentContainer {
  position: sticky;
  padding-left: 100px;
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan, but when I do that, it stays fixed and does not stay with the user when they scroll down...

Comment: It stays fixed? That's strange, because your use-case is why `position: sticky` has been invented: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: Maybe your CSS rule is overwritten by another CSS rule with higher priority? I don't know if you're an experienced CSS developer, but maybe you'll like my article collecting strategies and idea how to hunt down this kind of bugs: https://www.beyondjava.net/gentle-introduction-css

Comment: Thank you. I will look for any such conflicts...